# PyCharm Community Edition problems with read-only status on project files

Tags: pycharm

I'm using PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.1 on Windows 7 64bit.

Whenever i open my project in PyCharm, a window comes up saying
    "Clear Read-Only Status":
    [x] Using file system.
    [] Using version control inegration.
Pressing [OK] has no effect.

Later, when i try to save the project, it says:
Could not save project!
Unable to save project files, check permissions blabla ...

On exiting, it says:
    Unsaved Project.
    PyCharm was unable to save some project files,
    are you sure you want to close this project anyway?

Obviously, i checked read-only status in Windows explorer and forced all files to read/write access.
But that doesn't solve the issue.
Also i can edit the files with other text editors and save them just fine.
Most files are under revision control in a Mercurial (Hg) repository, if that matters.

This is getting really annoying.
Any suggestions?

(Another thing that annoys me is my inability to control line breaks in stackoverflow text! Just never looks how i intended. If someone has a hint for that, I'd be glad too)

Comment: try running pycharm in administrator mode

Comment: admin mode doesn't make a difference for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got an answer from JetBrains support. It is a known issue:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90978 (and related issues).

The workaround described in http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90978#comment=27-721097 solved the issue for me.

Quoted from there:

In Explorer only files have effective RO flags; changing RO flags applies only to files if you were to use the Properties panel. Folders remain with the RO flag for some reason, even though they're perfectly writeable. The IDE fails to "not honour" the RO flag and use ACL instead to see if it can write in a directory. To quickly fix this run these commands in cmd.exe running as an Admin:

```
attrib -r +s C:\WorkingDir
attrib -r +s C:\WorkingDir\*
```

Running those two line removes the Ready-Only flag from FOLDERS and replaces it with a System flag instead.

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks - i used http://superuser.com/a/653955/35020 - is /s flag needed when using this here? Would like to use this here cause dropbox keeps resetting the read only flag (dropbox or the little green men)

Comment: Forget it - system flag does nothing in my case - i think it's safer to use the line suggested in the other post than messing with the system flag `attrib -r c:\folder\*.* /s /d`

Comment: I find the `+s` option to add a "system file attribute" to add nothing (this fix still works when omitting it) and in my case, it caused a python script to fail when trying to modify a file in the target directory (Permission Denied error). I did the above commands from Scrontch but changed `+s` to `-s` to undo this error. More info on the `attrib` command: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Does anyone have a Mac fix?

Comment: The point of `+s` is to have windows still respect a `desktop.ini` if present

Comment: +1 to Praxiteles - anyone know of an OSX fix? Seeing the same exact error with PyCharm CE 2016.2.3 and Python 2.7.10, on OSX Sierra 10.12

Don't see mention of OSX in the above linked YouTrack thread.

The issue goes away when I'm logged in as root instead of my regular account. Could this be some kind of OSX permissions config I need to do?

Comment: For me, the above command with `attrib -r +s` did not work, but `attrib -R -S -H /S /D path\to\code\*` did. I'm on PyCharm 2020.3 on Windows 10. (Well, I'm troubleshooting something for a friend. I'm actually on Linux and on Mac OS, where I didn't run into this issue.)

Answer (score 40):

For OS X,

Navigate to your project directory and run

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) .
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/

Comment: this works for pycharm running on Windows 11 with the sourcecode over WSL 2 (Ubuntu 20.04). I executed this code from the Ubuntu WSL terminal. It unlocks the file that I had locked. But if I lock again, I would have to run the command to unlock it. Weird. But it works. Hope this helps.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution also works on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 12):

I experienced this problem every time I added a new Django app.

Run this command inside the container.

```
 chmod -R 777 ./
```

Comment: For container based project this is the case . Thanks .  worked for me

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu. Using equivalent for attrib - [fatattr](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/fatattr), solved the issue. I also found out that "Clear Read-Only Status" works fine when PyCharm is running with root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is user privileges, i think. I came across the same issue and found that i was creating the python file with root user and could access it from my user account's PyCharm. I created the python file with user account and it works great, doesn't show this error.

Comment: Same here, someone ran `sudo pycharm.sh` and all kinds of files got created with root as the owner, which pycharm couldn't access. Wrong chmod, too.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of you have saved a file with opening the IDE in root mode, you cannot edit that file as a normal user. For that purpose, you need to have root permissions.

With my experience, I can write and edit other files at any time, which are not saved under the root mode

Answer (score -1):

My friend had the same problem on his linux machine. I just went to the location on files, and right clicked to the properties and changed the read-only to the read and write and applied.

It worked!